# Why is 1em not based on the defined 16px?

Tags: css, html

I have some serious problem understanding the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body{
    font-size:16px;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1em;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Sample Text</p>


</body>
</html>
```

I understand that the font size is now 32px because I put 2em which will be twice of 16, but why is the margin-bottom and line-height 32px even though its 1em?

Comment: The `em` value of the margin is computed based on the element it is being applied to - which in this case is the `<p>` with a computed `font-size` of 32px.

Comment: Use rem, 1rem = 16px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using em as font size unit, It is relative to the immediate parent or the same element which is having font-size declared. Here your `<p>` has font size of 2em(that means 32px) So the line height and margin is now considering 32px as its base value and em is calculating based on this new value.

But if you are using rem as the unit, it will always take body/html font size as its base value.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you should use `rem` instead of `em`.

Take a look [here](https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/).

`em` is relative to the font-size of its nearest parent while `rem` is relative to the root font-size.

I'd like to think "r" of `rem` as the "root em". And the root mean the `html` not the `body` element.

```js
console.log("padding of div em  : " + window.getComputedStyle(em).padding);
console.log("padding of div rem : " + window.getComputedStyle(rem).padding);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
div.parent {
  font-size: 20px;
}
div.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
#em {
  padding: 1em;
}
#rem {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="em" class="child">1em</div>
  <div id="rem" class="child">1rem</div>
</div>
```